# How to make a TextView bold?

Tags: java, android, textview, bold

I want to be able to make a TextView bold. This is how I am setting it's appearance (I need to do this in code):

```
nameText.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.BlueText);
priceText.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.BlueText);
changeText.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.BlueText);
```

Here is my style.xml

```
  <!-- Blue Color -->
   <style name="BlueText">
        <item name="android:textColor">#4871A8</item>
    </style>
```

How can I make sure my TextView is bolded?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  <!-- Blue Color -->
   <style name="BlueText">
        <item name="android:textColor">#4871A8</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, if you want to do the same without any XML at all, you can do this:

TextView myText = new TextView(this);
myText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
myText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);